# Including elements in the structure view of TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I would like to include elements in the structure view of TeXstudio so that I could easily navigate through the document. These new elements should be together with the section titles in the structure view. The command `paragraph` does it partially. It includes the title in the structure, but it does not typeset the text in a new paragraph. Is there an existing command includes the title in the structure view, but that does not create a new section or subsection? There are more details in the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Including elements in the structure view of TeXstudio

\section{Section 1}

The name ``Section 1'' is in the structure view.

\subsection{Subsection A}

The name ``Subsection A'' is in the structure view.

\paragraph{Emphasis}

Text of emphasis with \verb|paragraph|. It enters the structure view, but the typeset text does not appear in a new paragraph (normal behavior of \verb|paragraph|). Is there an existing command that emphasizes text and puts the text in the structure view, as \verb|paragraph| does, but that typesets the text in a new paragraph?

\paragraph{Emphasis 2} \ \par

This is a fix, with \verb|\ \par|. But there is probably a better way.

\end{document}
```

[image: screen]

Comment: A workaround could be using `\label{}`. I don't know if any changes can be made to `texstudio.ini`, to get the result or if this needs additional implementation of new features

Comment: Label is not a good workaround because the labels appear in another position of the structure view. To facilitate navigation, the new items should be together with the section titles in the structure view.